# modify the data-donut attribute of the divs from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, d3.js

My javascript

```
 var currentMonth= new Date().getMonth();
    if (demo.length >= currentMonth){
    var d3data = demo[currentMonth];
```

// **output will be `["23", "19"]`**

now i need to update output values to  `#donut and #donut1 (data-donut="")`

**values are coming from json it may change according to month**

for reference i have added FIDDLE
http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3166/

```
<div class="zipper">
    <div class="current">
        <div class="title_text">current</div>
<div id="donut" data-donut="42"></div>///here in the data-donut value
    </div>
    <div class="target">
         <div class="title_text">Target</div>
<div id="donut1" data-donut="62"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Any help is Appreciated

Comment: $('#donut').data('donut',23) ?

Comment: Thank you for answering, problem is  values are coming from json it may change according to month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to assign the values from the array (assuming the array is the result after parsing it from json)

```
var d3data = demo[currentMonth];
// assuming that this results in d3data = ["23", "19"];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("div[data-donut]").each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('data-donut', d3data[i]);
    });
});
```

The first value of the array will be assigned to the first div and the second value to the second one.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3169/)

Comment: fiddle is working fine but its not helping me, what to do??

can i assign the d3dat value to x??

like 
`var currentMonth= new Date().getMonth();
    if (demo.length >= currentMonth){
    var d3data = demo[currentMonth];
// output will be ["23", "19"]
var x = [];
d3data = x;
$("div[data-donut]").each(function(i) {
       $(this).attr('data-donut', x[i]);
});`

Comment: i am getting the values in console.log but **values are not updating in the div** it is working in js fiddle not in my code

Comment: The code must be executed when the document is fully loaded as in JSFiddle. I have added this to the answer (not in JSFiddle because it is already doing that).

Comment: as you suggested i tried ** var currentMonth= new Date().getMonth(); if (demo.length >= currentMonth){ debugger; var d3data = demo[currentMonth]; console.log(d3data); //assuming that this results in d3data = ["23", "19"]; $( document ).load(function() { $("div[data-donut]").each(function(i) { $(this).attr('data-donut', d3data[i]); }); }); } **But still not working, is it i am doing wrong here(i am getting the values in console)

Comment: `$(document).ready` not `$(document).load` within the script tag within the body tag at the end

Comment: still it is not happening, may be i am using in popup??
but all the code including popup is in same html, i dont know what i am doing wrong?? but it is working in fiddle, thanks mate

Comment: thanks mate! finally your solution worked. i appreciate it,keep the good work

Answer (score 1):

This will work

```
    obj = ["23", "19"];
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);

    for (var i = 0,j=1; i < keys.length; i++,j++) {
       var val = obj[keys[i]];
       document.getElementById("donut"+j).setAttribute("data-donut", val); 
   
    }

   
<div class="zipper">
    <div class="current">
        <div class="title_text">current</div>
<div id="donut1" data-donut="42"></div>///here in the data-donut value
    </div>
    <div class="target">
         <div class="title_text">Target</div>
<div id="donut2" data-donut="62"></div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for not explaining the problem properly
**values are coming from json it may change according to month**
so can you please help me

Comment: check the updated code and you must have to give the div name like donut1,donut2,.....sequentially. so you will get desired result.

Comment: i am getting this error **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null**

Comment: can you show your updated code in code snippet or http://jsfiddle.net/? so i will be issue to understand.

Comment: sorry or the late replay i have updated your code in this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/3170/] still getting same error

Comment: Change id of your html tag <div id="donut1" data-donut="42"></div> as donut1,donut2 etc....Then it works

Comment: You have to call this statement only once  document.getElementById("donut"+j).setAttribute("data-donut", val); in a loop

Comment: same error iam getting **Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null ** but it is working in fiddle

Comment: Have you used the same code check again id of you html tag.

Comment: Then, It must be worked. Are you getting any errors now? without it i can't find your issue. if you have placed your code on live server then show me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62738/discussion-between-manjunath-siddappa-and-yatin-mistry).

Comment: sorry i dont have a server access you have join me access or skype i can show you

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to modify the **data-donut** attribute of the divs. Hope this will help

document.getElementsById("donut").setAttribute("data-donut","<***your value***>");
document.getElementsById("donut1").setAttribute("data-donut","<***your value***>");

Comment: sorry for not explaining the problem properly
**values are coming from json it may change according to month**
so can you please help me

Comment: No matter from where the values come...after receiving the value, store it in a variable and use the variable in the above syntax. Only exclude the double quotes when populating values from variables

Comment: Sample: document.getElementsById("donut").setAttribute("data-donut",**<your variable>**);

Comment: i have tried your example, but its not working .**Let me know if i am doing wrong**`var currentMonth= new Date().getMonth();
    if (demo.length >= currentMonth){
    debugger;
    var d3data = demo[currentMonth];
    console.log(d3data);
\\output will be ["23", "19"]
     document.getElementById("donut").setAttribute("data-donut", d3data[0]);
     document.getElementById("donut").setAttribute("data-donut", d3data[1]);
    console.log(d3data[1]);`

Answer (score 1):

This is not json format ["23", "19"]

e.g this is an array

```
var d3data = ["23", "19"]; 

$('#donut').data('donut', d3data[0]); 

$('#donut1').data('donut',d3data[1]);
```

Comment: i am getting the values from your solution but it is not updating the div, can you please help me

Comment: $('#donut').html(d3data[0]);  $('#donut1').html(d3data[1]);

Comment: i am getting the values as numbers in html but it is showing the chart

Comment: ["23", "19"] looks like a valid json array